# Как объяснить поговорку "В Рязани грибы с глазами"?

Tags: пословицы

Недавно мне из Константиново привези милый сувенир на эту тему, а также  показали фотографии памятника.

Известны **две легенды** с объяснением (историческая и лингвистическая), но полного доверия они не вызывают.

Если считать, что это тема небылиц, то вроде бы неплохая версия. Но тогда возникает вопрос: а есть ли похожие небылицы, построенные **на рифмовке** топонимических названий? В каких еще городах возможны такие памятники?

Если такие примеры найдутся, то это, вероятно, подтвердит **версию небылиц**. Кстати, **исторический** вариант происхождения поговорки (о помятых грибах) надо подтверждать документально (не знаю, есть ли такие источники).

**А какое толкование** вы считаете более подходящим? Или есть еще и другие?

[Грибы с глазами](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/oFRL/Ld17GXved)

Comment: Вот-вот! Не ***у** Рязани,* а ***в** Рязани.)* Обычно звучит она так: *А у нас в Рязани грибы с глазами.*

Comment: Артем, а разве в городе растут грибы?

Comment: Странно, согласен. Если и растут, то, конечно, не в самом городе как таковом. Но ведь может иметься в виду и Рязанская область вообще... Мне кажется, это просто шутка, которая рифмуется хорошо.

Comment: Тогда уж не шутка, а небылица.  Вот я и хотела узнать, есть ли еще похожие, основанные на рифмовке.

Comment: Да, интересно найти ещё таких.

Answer (score 1):

В период возникновения народной поговорки, т.н."телеги": "В Рязани грибы с глазами, их - едят, они - глядят"  был популярен вокально-инструментальный ансамбль "Цветы" под управлением Стаса Намина. Особо популярной была композиция "Есть глаза у цветов!". Где её только не исполняли! И на радио, и на ТВ, и на мини-грампластинках была выпущена запись!  Рязанское население переделало "глаза у цветов" на "грибы с глазами". Таково происхождение этого фольклора.